# Calculate the pupillary distance of a image with face.com api

Tags: face-recognition

I am using face.com api. With this API, I can find the right and left eye coordinates. Now I want to find the PD (Pupillary Distance).

For this I am using the distance formula

```
d=sqrt((x2-x1)(x2-x1)+(y2-y1)(y2-y1))
```

but I am not getting appropriate result by this.
Please tell me where I am wrong?

Comment: Are the units (ie pixels, cm, inches) of your x,y points the same as your expected output units (usually mm)? How far off are your answers?

Answer (score 0):

An initial inspection says that the face.com API returns x,y coordinates measured as a percentage of the image size.  You are probably expecting PD to be measured in mm.  You need to find a way to determine the scale of your image at the z-depth of the face.  Once you convert from percentages to real units, you will be able to compute PD.